# Algorithm to obtain indices of list where list element resets to near zero

Tags: python, list, algorithm, sorting, indexing

I have list of increasing and decreasing float values:

[image]

As you can see in the image, the values may increase or decrease and may suddenly reset to
near zero value. I want to know exactly where these values reset to near zero value.

I tried something like this:

```
# input list of floats
# floats = [...]

# find the absolute difference between consecutive values
diff_floats = [abs(floats[i] - floats[i-1]) for i in range(1, len(floats))]

# Sort the list in descending order
sorted_diff_floats = sorted(diff_floats, reverse=True)

# Calculate the average of the top 14 differences
threshold = sum(sorted_diff_floats[:14]) / 14

# Count the number of values greater than the threshold
print(len([value for value in diff_floats if value > threshold]))
```

I hard coded `14`, since I know that empirically the reset did not happen more than 7 times. So better to get top 14 differences average, instead of average of all values.

I am yet to get index of these resets which I can easily get by modifying last line of the code. But I feel the logic can still be improved to work on any input list of floats without considering the empirical knowledge of 7 resets.

How what could be the generatlised solution?

Comment: Looks like measured data, so in a first step I would eliminate outliers. Maybe also smooth the values a bit (sliding average with small window size).  After this I would try to find the return-to-zero positions

Comment: You write you expect about 14 of those, but in the image I can only identify 4 or 5... Can you provide actual data for `floats` in your Python code? And could you then add the expected output (list of indices)?

Answer (score 1):

The notion of "suddenly reset to near zero" is open for interpretation; like when is a move not so sudden anymore, and when is a value not near enough to zero.

But here is an idea you could use:

Consider only the diffs that are greater than the *median* of the diffs, and then only consider "near zero" those values whose difference with zero is less than that median:

```
jumps = [i
         for i, (diff, val) in enumerate(zip(diff_floats, floats[1:]), start=1)
            if diff > median_diff > abs(val)
        ]
```

Answer (score 1):

Whenever I see the tag "algorithm" along with the tag of a language (here "python") I assume that it is acceptable to use pseudo-code. I will offer an answer in Ruby, which can be read as pseudo-code, helped along with explanations I will provide where needed.

Let's use an example. (I'll use integers but the code is the same if the values are floats.) Suppose:

```
x = [4, 3, 0, -1, -2, 0, 2, 1, 0, -4]
```

which can be graphed as follows:

```
 4 x                
 3   x                  
 2             x     
 1               x   
 0     x     x     x    
-1       x    
-2         x           
-3                    
-4                   x
   0 1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 9
```

Next define, by whatever means is deemed appropriate, a *threshold value* such that an element of `x` is to be identified (by its index) if the value equals zero and the absolute value of the previous or following value in `x` is greater than or equal to the threshold value.

Suppose:

```
threshold = 3
```

Now let:

```
a1 = x.each_index.each_cons(3).to_a
  #=> [[0, 1, 2], [1, 2, 3], [2, 3, 4], [3, 4, 5],
  #    [4, 5, 6], [5, 6, 7], [6, 7, 8], [7, 8, 9]]
```

It's not really important how this calculation works, just what is produced, which should be readily apparent. `[1, 2, 3]`, contains, for example, indices `1`, `2` and `3` into the array `x`.

Continuing,

```
a2 = a1.select do |e1, e2, e3|
  x[e2] == 0 and (x[e1].abs >= threshold or x[e3].abs >= threshold)
end
  #=> [[1, 2, 3], [7, 8, 9]]
```

Lastly,

```
a2.map { |e1, e2, e3| e2 } # or a2.map { |a| a[1] }
  #=> [2, 8]
```

This indicates that the zero values of `x` at indices `2` and `8` (but not at `5`) have been identified.